# Getting Wireshark to to work

Tags: linux, wireshark, broadcom

I'm having serious issues in **getting Wireshark** to work on both of my computers. I can successfully see whats going in and out of my notebook but I can't figure out how to **sniff from all computers** in my network (secure by *WPA2 AES+TKIP*).

My adapters are: *Broadcom BCM4313* (kernel module: *brcmsmac*), and second is some *Atheros* driven by *ath5k* kernel module. What's worth mentioning I do can sniff networks SSIDs from other networks on monitor modes on both cards.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: WPA2 gives you a private channel between your computer and the base station. You **cannot** snoop on other computer's communications with this security mechanism. If you want to, then you need to choose a weaker security mechanism. (well you can, but that's another kettle of fish)

Comment: @Petesh Thanks for great comment. As soon as I opened the network and set to monitor mode I was able to sniff all the packets :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest setting up "monitor mode";  there is a "Monitor mode" checkbox in the Capture Options window in Wireshark, there's also the command line -I  to capture in monitor mode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is monitor mode. See [Turning on monitor mode](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode) for details.